# How to see what has gone wrong (exception)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, exception, sqlconnection

I'm working on an application that opens a database connection and retrieving data from it to be showed to the user. Everything looks fine in the code of what I can see, but something is wrong because an exception gets thrown in the method below. I have placed a breakpoint at "conn.Open();" and it's there the exception is thrown.

I have no idea how to find out what the actual error is and how to solve it, and hope to get some help here. The stack trace for the exception can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/uj5A9Rar) if it helps.

The exception is: System.ApplicationException: Error in the application

Thanks in advance!

the method that throws the exception:

```
public List<Movie> GetMovies() {

    var movieTitles = new List<Movie>(100);

    using (var conn = CreateConnection()) {
        try {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_GetMovies", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            conn.Open();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                var movieIDIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("MovieID");
                var nameIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Name");
                var yearIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Year");
                var lengthIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Length");
                var summaryIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Summary");

                while (reader.Read()) {
                    movieTitles.Add(new Movie {
                        MovieID = reader.GetInt32(movieIDIndex),
                        Name = reader.GetString(nameIndex),
                        Year = reader.GetInt32(yearIndex),
                        Length = reader.GetInt32(lengthIndex),
                        Summary = reader.GetString(summaryIndex),
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            throw new ApplicationException("An error occured!");
        }

    }

    movieTitles.TrimExcess();

    return movieTitles;
}
```

Heres the base class for the class containing the method above:

```
public abstract class DALBase {
    private static string _connectionString;

    static DALBase() {
            _connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOfTheDatabase_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }

    protected SqlConnection CreateConnection() {
        return new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

from web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NameOfTheDatabase_ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xx.xxx.x;Initial Catalog=The_Catalog;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: If the exception is thrown at the point of opening the connection, my guess would be that there is something wrong with the connection string. Confirm that the connection string is valid by opening up VS2010 connection dialog and building the string using the dialog. If you can connect then that rules this out - if you can't then the connection string is not a valid one and you have your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
throw new ApplicationException("An error occured!");
```

to

```
throw;
```

and you will get the actual exception and message.

Comment: If you do that, there is no need to include the catch at all.

Comment: True enough, but this will get you the answer quickly, and in the end you should be handling the exception. So less lines of code to change.

Comment: Well, that actually gave me the following: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
- System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32() +5057461
- System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i) +38

Comment: @JasonCraig, well, great! Now you know where the problem is so that you can fix it.

Comment: Is there a possibility of NULL values?

Comment: Thanks alot for this. As you say it gave me the answer quickly.

Comment: This is a bad idea - it would be better to remove the try/catch entirely. Catch blocks which *just* do "throw" simply add clutter (unless they're making that the behaviour for a very specific exception, when a more general one will be handled differently by a subsequent catch block).

Comment: @JasonCraig: As I've said, this isn't an ideal solution, as it leaves your code more cluttered than it should be.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I agree with you, I was just trying to get to the root of the exception first. I always assume these types of posts are hacked to avoid posting the exact code.

Answer (score 5):

Your try/catch isn't really doing *anything* useful - quite the reverse, it's *removing* information.

Unless you're *specifically* expecting `ApplicationException` from this code (ick), just remove the try/catch entirely, and let the exception bubble up to the top of the stack. Now you'll get the *real* exception, full of informationy goodness, instead of the anaemic "Something went wrong, but I really have no idea what" exception you're currently throwing.

If you want to see the exception in the debugger, just change the debugger settings to break in as soon as there's an exception - you don't need a try/catch block for that.

Answer (score 4):

The stack trace you post actually tells you the exception, which in this case is an [`ApplicationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception.aspx) which has 'bubbled up from'* an [`TargetInvocationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.aspx):

```
TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

*The thing is, you catch the *proper* exception and then throw your own exception (of a type that shouldn't actually be thrown but only derived from to create specific, custom exception types eligible to be thrown.)

Incidentally, `TargetInvocationException`'s *can* be tough to nail down, static constructors being a culprit I make mind to keep aware of, but not knowing your code I can't say.

Answer (score 1):

You're catching every kind of exception and not using them at all for analysis:

This:

```
catch 
{
    throw new ApplicationException("An error occured!");
}
```

should be this:

```
catch (Exception e) 
{
    //look at e here
}
```

Now, the e variable will have all the information you need.

Although, I'm assuming you have the try catch in there for the debugging purposes. If not it would be better to just remove it altogether and let the exception find it's way up the stack.

Comment: ... but that information will be lost unless you're debugging. It won't be present in the `ApplicationException`.

Comment: @Jon absolutely, I'm assuming he added the try catch because he's in a debugging session trying to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Yes, it will help in that case - but why continue to throw such an information-free exception?

Comment: @Jon I wouldn't, I actually changed my answer to reflect that position. No sense in throwing a useless exception if he's just trying to analyze the real exception. This was all under the idea that he was having issues seeing the exception without the try catch in the first place, because he mentioned adding a break point. I'm gathering his VS instance isn't set up to automatically catch on exceptions or something to that effect.

Comment: Note that `catch (Exception e) {}` may cause a compiler warning as it introduces an unreferenced local variable.  Instead, use `catch {}` and look at `$exception` within the debugger.